# Configure an ELK cluster in docker containers

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-2.0, docker-container

I'm trying to configure an ELK cluster using 2 docker containers.

I'm using the following image:

- es241_l240_k461: Elasticsearch 2.4.1, Logstash 2.4.0, and Kibana 4.6.1. (reference: https://hub.docker.com/r/sebp/elk/ )

I have created 2 docker containers for that image with `docker-compose`; each works perfectly in standalone mode.

I want to link the 2 ELK nodes between each other in way to create the cluster, but I haven't found a proper solution.
The Elasticsearch node in *container1* doesn't communicate with the Elasticsearch node in *container2*.

These are the two `docker-compose.yml`:

**CONTAINER1:**

```
version: '2'
services:
  elasticsearch01:
    image: sebp/elk:es241_l240_k461
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
      - "5044:5044"
    volumes:
      - /opt/ELK1/logstash/conf.d:/etc/logstash/conf.d
    privileged: true
```

**CONTAINER2:**

```
version: '2'
services:
  elasticsearch02:
    image: sebp/elk:es241_l240_k461
    ports:
      - "5602:5601"
      - "9201:9200"
      - "9301:9300"
      - "5045:5044"
    volumes:
      - /opt/ELK2/logstash/conf.d:/etc/logstash/conf.d
    privileged: true
```

I'have configured the `elasticsearch.yml` inside the docker containers in this way:

**NODE IN CONTAINER1:**

```
cluster.name: elasticsearchcluster
node.name: node1
network.host: 0.0.0.0
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1", "172.21.0.2"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

**NODE IN CONTAINER2:**

```
cluster.name: elasticsearchcluster
node.name: node2
network.host: 0.0.0.0
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1", "172.22.0.2"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

The key is the **`discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts`** parameter: I don't have the real IP address, because it's a docker container.

I tried `docker inspect elasticsearch01`, I have the following `"IPAddress"` property:

```
    "NetworkSettings": {
        ...
        "Networks": {
            "ELK1_default": {
                ...
                "Gateway": "172.22.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.22.0.2",
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work if I set that IP address.

How to configure the cluster properly?

EDIT

Trying the host ip-address and the port, the node 1 starts, the node 2 fails with no errors.

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1", "192.168.0.1:9300"] -> OK
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1", "192.168.0.2:9300"] -> FAILS with no errors
```

Comment: Wouldn't `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1", elasticsearch01, elasticsearch02]` work? Alternatively, just setup a separate elasticsearch container in `docker-compose` and then scale it as much as you want. A good example is here: https://hub.docker.com/r/itzg/elasticsearch/

Comment: No, I've tried with the names instead of IP-addresses, but it doesn't work. It seems that it search the nodes inside the container, not outside. Obviously I have only one node in each container.

Comment: Have you looked at the link I've sent you? It would be the right solution for your problem.

Comment: Yes, I've looked it, but it refers to the version 1.3.5 of Elasticsearch. I'm using the 2.4.1 version.

Comment: Do you have to use `2.4.1` or it can be the latest version?

Comment: I have to use this version, I can't upgrade to the newest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Evaldas Buinauskas, I've found the solution with the stack!

First, **we need only one docker-compose.yml**.
In that file we need to configure **two services** (one for each container to create), and **a network** to be shared between the two services.

This is the new `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  elk1:
    environment:
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m"
    image: sebp/elk:es241_l240_k461
    networks:
      - elk_net
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
      - "5044:5044" 
    volumes:
      - /opt/elk/logstash/conf.d:/etc/logstash/conf.d
    privileged: true
  elk2:
    environment:
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m"
    image: sebp/elk:es241_l240_k461
    networks:
      - elk_net
    ports:
      - "5602:5601"
      - "9201:9200"
      - "9301:9300"
      - "5045:5044"
    depends_on:
      - elk1  
    volumes:
      - /opt/elk/logstash/conf.d:/etc/logstash/conf.d
    privileged: true  
networks:
  elk_net:
    driver: bridge
```

The command `docker-compose up` will create 3 elements:

1. the container elk1
2. the container elk2
3. the network elk_net

With the `docker network inspect elk_net` command we can view the (docker) ip addresses assigned to the 2 containers.

The elasticsearch.yml files have to be configured as follows:

```
cluster.name: elasticsearchcluster
node.name: node1
network.host: 0.0.0.0
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
network.publish_host: ${IP_ADDRESS_ELK1}
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["${IP_ADDRESS_ELK2}"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1

cluster.name: elasticsearchcluster
node.name: node2
network.host: 0.0.0.0
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
network.publish_host: ${IP_ADDRESS_ELK2}
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["${IP_ADDRESS_ELK1}"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

With this configuration, the cluster works perfectly: the two nodes are merged correctly and the Http get to each elasticsearch server returns all the documents saved in the 2 nodes.

Comment: Hi @Alessandro with your solution , I want to put my container in different nodes on cluster (different instance) is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a prepared docker file with ELK stack, you could go for something like this:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:2.4.1
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elk

  elasticsearch_slave:
    image: elasticsearch:2.4.1
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    command: elasticsearch --discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch

  logstash:
    image: logstash:2.3.3
    hostname: logstash
    networks:
      - elk
    volumes:
      - ./logstash.conf:/config/logstash.conf
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 5044:5044
    command: logstash -f /config/logstash.conf

  kibana:
    image: kibana:4.5.1
    hostname: kibana
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
      - logstash
    ports:
      - 5601:5601

networks:

  elk:
    driver: bridge
```

Once you start your images using `docker-compose up -d`, then you can scale slaves using following command `docker-compose scale elasticsearch_slave=5`

Once that's done - you'll have 5 slaves + client node that opens up port 9200 as a gateway to the whole cluster.

For instance, after doing that, `http://localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v` displays following:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I can try it but in this way I don't have anymore the advantage of a unique stack.

Comment: @AlessandroC You might have some other advantages here. :)

Comment: see my solution! it works also with the stack. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @AlessandroC I'm glad that you made it :)

Comment: Hi @EvaldasBuinauskas with your solution , I want to put my container in different nodes on cluster (different instance) is it possible?